# Unable to find the exact match

Tags: excel, vba, find

need to find the column name "MDP JUL" however it selecting "Net MDP JUL+3" this column

```vb
For J = 2 To FCL

    Inf.Activate
    FC = Range("F" & J).Value
    temp.Activate
    Sheets(Flash).Select
    FLC = Range("2:2").Find(what:=FC, MatchCase:=True, lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues).Column
```

please check and do the needfull

Comment: Could you please post your full code. This will make it easier for us to fully understand your issue.

Comment: From what I can understand, you want to match the entire header name, rather than just partial. In that case, how about using `xlWhole` instead of `xlPart`?

Comment: Required Colum is in  “MDP JUL” but it is mapping to next column  as  “Net MDP JUL+3”.

Comment: FLC = Range("2:2").Find(what:=FC, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Column